# Macbook to Apple TV: Airplay possible?

Tags: macos, macbook, appletv, airplay

Have a 2nd generation Apple TV hooked up.  Am able to AirPlay with my iPhone, but not with the Macbook.  Not sure if this is even possible, but Googling around seems to return some chitchat about it, but nothing concrete.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Considering [the Airplay web page displays a Mac sending the signal](http://www.apple.com/itunes/airplay/), it sould be perfectly possible. As per [this answer](http://forums.macrumors.com/showthread.php?t=1051376) on the MacRumors forums, it seems to require iTunes 10.1 though:

> As of iOS 4.2.1 (GM) and iTunes 10.1
>
> (Audio/Video)
>
> What will work:
>
> iPhone -> New Apple TV/AirPlay enabled device*
> iPod touch -> New Apple TV/AirPlay enabled device*
> iPad -> New Apple TV/AirPlay enabled device*
> Mac/PC** -> New Apple TV/AirPlay enabled device*
>
> [...]
>
> *AirPlay Enabled Device: Home Theatre System, Receivers, Airport Express and Sound Dock
> ** Mac/PC will require at least iTunes 10.1 for AirPlay to work with video

Airplay without video was called AirTunes. iTunes up to 10.0 only supported that.

Comment: I have iTunes 10.1.1, but I'm failing to see where/how you actually initiate the AirPlay.

Comment: @gravyface On the bottom right of the iTunes window. [See here](http://i.imgur.com/fhz3u.jpg).

Answer (score 2):

You might also want to take a look at Erica Sadun's [Air Play Utilities](http://ericasadun.com/ftp/AirPlay/):

- AirPlayer: Transform your Mac into an AirPlay-compatible display.
- AirFlick: Serve files and URLs to Apple TV
- Bruce: Display time, day, local weather, RSS-feeds, or live screen shots on ATV, among other features
- AirVideo: Client Bare-bones way to watch your AirVideo Server-supplied video on a Mac.

Answer (score 1):

You may want to check out [airfoil](http://www.rogueamoeba.com/airfoil/mac/)

Comment: Airfoil connects to AirTunes speakers, which the Apple TV already is (or at least Airplay). It'd only help if the user wanted to use something other than iTunes.

Comment: This looks great too.

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out by Apple on their AirPlay Support website, any 2011 MacBook is capable of supporting AirPlay mirroring and can mirror to an Apple TV.

http://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201343.

---

Here are the supported devices for AirPlay mirroring.

- iMac (Mid 2011 or newer)
- Mac mini (Mid 2011 or newer)
- MacBook Air (Mid 2011 or newer)
- MacBook Pro (Early 2011 or newer)
- Mac Pro (Late 2013 or newer)

---

**Newer Macs**

On newer Macs, it is very simple to mirror your screen onto an AirPlay-compatible device such as an Apple TV. There is an AirPlay status menu on the Menu Bar.

*Steps*

1. Ensure AirPlay menu is visible
2. Click AirPlay menu item
3. Select Apple TV

[image: AirPlay Menu]

---

**Older Macs**

If you are using an earlier Mac, you are not doomed however; while it is not officially supported, there is software out there that will let you bypass the compatibility issue, and to be quite honest, many of these apps work very well.

Here are the main apps that let you do just that.

- AirParrot 2 (**$14.99**) - http://www.airsquirrels.com/airparrot/
- AirServer (**$14.99**) - http://www.airserver.com

I have personally tested out **AirParrot** and was surprised at how well it works.